# Ignoring folder with large number of directories

Tags: powershell

I have written a PowerShell script that traverses over a directory and captures a list of folder names that are nested inside. It uses the following loop to achieve this

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $targetPath -Directory -Recurse |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Fullname" |
    ForEach-Object {
        #log folder name
    }
```

However I want the script to skip directories that have a configured number of folders nested inside.

For example in the following example I do not want to capture the 'Folder C' because it has more than 3 folders nested.

```
Folder A/Folder AA
Folder A/Folder AB
Folder B/Folder BA
Folder C/Folder CA #DO NOT CAPTURE
Folder C/Folder CB #DO NOT CAPTURE
Folder C/Folder CC #DO NOT CAPTURE
Folder C/Folder CD #DO NOT CAPTURE
Folder D
```

So I would like my output of the script to be

```
Folder A/Folder AA
Folder A/Folder AB
Folder B/Folder BA
Folder D
```

How can I edit my script to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to exclude folders on the top level you could do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $targetPath -Directory | Where-Object {
    (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Directory).Count -le 3
} | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Directory -Recurse
} | Select-Object -Expand Fullname
```

If you want to exclude any (sub)folder that contains more than 3 subfolders you'll have to implement the recursion yourself. `Get-ChildItem` does not provide that kind of filtering mechanism.

Comment: Thank you - I had to resort to writing my own recursion.